# How can "foil" be used as a verb?

Tags: verbs

What valid constructions with TO FOIL are there?

> He foiled my fixing the table.
>
> He foiled me fixing the table.
>
> He foiled me to fix the table.
>
> He foiled me from fixing the table.

Answer (score 2):

None of these is valid. You foil an action (usually a wrong one), not usually a person. You could say

> He foiled my attempts to fix the table.

but it's usually crimes, plots and so forth that are 'foiled'.

PS [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foil) does seem to regard 'foiling a person' as acceptable, but I as a British English speaker have never come across it.

Comment: I'd say that the "foil a person" version would be referring to the narrative definition of using one person to highlight certain characteristics of another (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foil_(narrative)). In this sense, the foil is acting on the target.

Comment: @JozefWoods - M-W give as an example _Her accident foiled her from becoming a dancer_ which sounds odd to me; I would say 'it foiled her _plans to_ become a dancer'.

Comment: I can imagine 'I/she/he was foiled [by something] in my/his/her/an attempt to do something'.

Comment: Are you sure that "He foiled my fixing the table" doesn't work?

Comment: Not to me as a British English speaker.